# How can I change the string received by readLine() method from NFD to NFC in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nfd

I need to input Hangul(Korean) with `readline()`. However, when input is received with `readline()`, consonants and vowels are separated. This is example:

```swift
let input = readLine()! // input: 한글
print(input) // ㅎㅏㄴㄱㅡㄹ
```

Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641199-readline/), `readline()` used UTF-8 method. I know that it can represent Hangul without any problem.

So, I think the reason is because Apple uses NFD method. So I used `precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping` and `precomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping` from NFD or NFKD way to NFC or NFKC way. But the result was the same...

```swift
let input = readLine()!
print(input.precomposeStringWithCanonicalMapping) // prints ㅎㅏㄴㄱㅡㄹ
print(input.precomposeStringWithCompatibilityMapping) // prints 하ㄴ그ㄹ
```

I'm not sure if my hypothesis is wrong or if the transformation method is wrong. I hope you can give me a clue to solve the problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on my terminal. Maybe something wrong on your terminal? What does `print(input.unicodeScalars.count)` print?

Comment: @Sweeper Oh, sry. I will fix readline() to readLine(). `print(input.unicodeScalars.count)` result is `6`.

Comment: I don't know if it helps,  but I have a european locale and keyboard, and when I copy paste the input string,  the output is unchanged.  If you copy paste the input:  do you get the expected result ?  (just to see if it's keyboard input configuration or some deeper OS behaviors)

Comment: @Christophe Thank you for helping me. I confirmed that it works normally when copying and pasting.